# Codeigniter Query Format Issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get data record from one table and to update into table 2 but I think, I am missing something, your help and time will really help me.

```
$this->db->set('employees.country','countries.countryName');
$this->db->join('countries', 'employees.country_code2 = countries.country_code2','inner');
$query = $this->db->update('countries');
```

I need to get countryName from Countries Table and Then Update Country Name in Employees Table based on matching country code.

Comment: Why there's `select` if you want to update data? You must read documentation first: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Comment: There is no need of it, after troubleshooting tries, I just added this for confirmation. I just updated the main code.

Comment: Aren't you using foreign keys ? If you use, then you wouldn't need to do this manual update.

Comment: Anything that can help, please share ...

Comment: Hey ! I checked this but this is not the solution I am working for. I need to update the country Name in my Table while foreign key only work for integer types

Comment: I'm wondering why you have country name in other table while you already have foreign key of id. You can get name of country by that country foreign key id (using joins)